# can't pass data from controller to view on ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

My problem about ajax. (asp.net mvc) Trying pass data from controller to view; but there is an error: 
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

There is no problem about saving to server. But I can't reach 'alert' on my code. My code is;

**CONTROLLER**

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Asker(Question q)
    {
        db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == 1).Questions.Add(q);

        db.SaveChanges();

        return Json(q);
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
<script>
    $( function()
    {
        $("#ask-btn").click(function () {

            var q = {};
            q.Que = $("#ask-txt").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/SomebodysPage/Asker",
                data: '{q: ' + JSON.stringify(q) + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert("It's alright.");
                },
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

My Question Class:

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }

    public string Que { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public virtual Answer Answer { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: What does your Question class look like? Does it have a property named Que?

Comment: Yes it is. I' ve added my Quesiton Class.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad practice to use the object itself to save data and at the same time as a view object.
View-model pattern dictates that use only needed properties  as entity object to save data, in your case Question class, and after save,
map only necessary data to a new object like QuestionModel for showing it to the client. For example if the client needs only the success or failure of the request
then return object with only one property with two possible states. Also User and Answer class could be problematic to serialize.
You should avoid returning complex objects as a response to the client. I suspect that User, Answer have some circular references,
which can not be json serialized. I am assuming that you are using the Entity framework, try with
with [NonSerialized] tag for a quick solution.

```
public class Question
{
public int QuestionId {get; set; }

public string Que {get; set; }

[ForeignKey ("User")]
public int UserId {get; set; }

[NonSerialized]
public virtual User User {get; set; }

 [NonSerialized]
 public virtual Answer Answer {get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the data you're sending from the ajax. Try this ajax call

```
<script>
    $( function()
    {
        $("#ask-btn").on('click', function () {

            var dataToSend = $("#ask-txt").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/SomebodysPage/Asker",
                data: {question: JSON.stringify(dataToSend) },
                contentType: "application/json;",
                success: function (response) {
                    if(response) { alert("It's alright."); }
                    else { console.log(response); }
                },
                error: function(response) {
                   console.log(response);
                }
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

Also, since you are passing in a JSON string, the controller is expecting a string and not an object of type `Question`. You should deserialize the string to an object of type `Question` like so:

```
   [HttpPost]

    public JsonResult Asker(string question)
    {
       Question q = new Question();
       JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
       try {
            //try to convert string to an object of type Question
            q = (Question)json_serializer.DeserializeObject(question);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            return Json(q);
        }
        //Now we have an object of type Question from the json
        db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == 1).Questions.Add(q);

        db.SaveChanges();

        return Json(q);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I've applied this changes, but problem not fixed.

Comment: SQL Server saving data. But there is no alert on my screen; and this error: "Internal Server 500". I can't use the data that returns from Json (q)

Comment: What was printed in the console of the browser? I added the console.log statement in javascript for this purpose. Hopefully, this provides more details on the error.